# python itertools.groupby datetime series by hour

Tags: python, python-3.x

The task is pretty simple and i'm able to partially accomplish it:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

    for timestamp, grp in itertools.groupby(transactions, lambda x: parse(x['date']).hour):
        group = list(grp)
        logger.info(f'{timestamp} : {len(group)}')
```

-> i get the `hour:count` array.

However i want to have a `datetime:count` array as a result (where `datetime` object represent one hour).

Does i have to build the `datetime` object in `lambda x` function? (i.e. get `x['date']).hour`, `x['date']).day`, `x['date']).month` etc. and create a new `datetime` using those values) or there is another way?

*sample input(transactions) contains data for weeks/months:*

```
[
 {
  'date': '2018-12-04T15:34:40+00:00',
  'data': 'blabla'
 },
 {
  'date': '2018-12-04T15:38:40+00:00',
  'data': 'blabla'
 },
 {
  'date': '2018-12-04T15:45:40+00:00',
  'data': 'blabla'
 },
]
```

*sample output:*

```
2018-12-04 13:00:00+00:00 : 6
2018-12-04 14:00:00+00:00 : 1
2018-12-04 15:00:00+00:00 : 2
```

Thank you

Comment: What is `parse(x['date'])` without the `.hour` method?

Comment: `dateutil.parser` from this kind of timestamp `2018-12-04T15:34:40+00:00`

Comment: Could you add some sample input and the expected output?

Comment: Could you please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: added output. input is not that relevant - a list of objects with `2018-12-04T15:34:40+00:00` (format) timestamps.

Comment: What are the contents of transactions? An array of ```datetime```  strings?

Comment: array of objects where each object contains `date` property in `2018-12-04T15:34:40+00:00` format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a datetime object as key, I used now as the date but you can use the original date:

```
import itertools
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

transactions = ['2018-12-04 13:{}0:00+00:00'.format(i) for i in range(6)] + \
               ['2018-12-04 14:{}0:00+00:00'.format(i) for i in range(1)] + \
               ['2018-12-04 15:{}0:00+00:00'.format(i) for i in range(2)]
for timestamp, grp in itertools.groupby(transactions, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.combine(parse(x).date(), datetime.time(parse(x).hour, 0, 0, 0))):
    count = list(grp)
    print('{}:{}'.format(timestamp, len(count)))
```

**Output**

```
2018-12-04 13:00:00:6
2018-12-04 14:00:00:1
2018-12-04 15:00:00:2
```

Comment: sorr, i don't get it. why do i need to parse transactions?

Comment: To transform them into datetime objects, and them use those objects as keys in the groupby

Comment: initially object's timestamps contain minutes / seconds.

Comment: ops i see now :) yeah so that was my question. you answer is that i should construct datetime object. btw `datetime.today()` gives a current timestamp but i need to use the one from parsed timestamp because the data contains more than a single day.

Comment: thats the final working version, please correct your answer: `lambda x: datetime.combine(parse(x['date']), time(parse(x['date']).hour, 0, 0, 0))`
so the key to solution was `datetime.combine` to create new `datetime` obj

Comment: good if you also know how to convert the `2018-12-04T15:34:40+00:00` format with `strptime`  I tried: `(datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'))` but i guess it have prob with timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm a `collections.Counter` fan:

```
from dateutils.parser import parse
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
for transaction in transactions:
    counter.update(str(parse(transaction['date'][:-12])),)
for key,value in sorted(counter.items()):
    print(f'{key}: {value}')
```

And here is a solution using list comprehension:

```
from dateutils.parser import parse
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter([str(parse(x['date'][:-12])) for x in transactions]) 

for key,value in sorted(counter.items()):
    print(f'{key}: {value}')
```

Comment: to be honest i'm not getting it. why counter? there is a list of thousands transactions for weeks / months. need to group the by the date, hour.  `for key, value in sorted(counter):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: On both examples?

Comment: Don't you want to count the occurrences of every 'date, hour' in transactions?

Comment: first have some typo here `]))),)
`. tried to remove extra bracers but then some error too.

Comment: No, i want to group the transactions by the date and the hour of the day.

Comment: You are right. The first have one extra ). I will fix that.

Comment: In the example output you gave you are listing the number of occurrences of date,hour. Isn't that a counting?

Comment: no, it's the count of the elements in group (transactions grouped by the hour)

Comment: So the sample input you gave doesn't correspond to the sample output. Please provide a real test case.

Comment: that is the real test case. Example: `2018-12-06 13:00:00` - group. `6` - elements in group.

Comment: topic name also contains `itertools.groupby` -> it is about the grouping.