# Applying pandas group function keeping other columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this data frame:
Input:

> `df= pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2007-01-01 07:14:00','2007-01-01 07:25:00','2007-01-01 08:00:00','2007-01-01 09:14:00','2007-01-01 09:33:12'],'sent':[0.32,0.34,0.45,0.7,0.22],'var1':[44,0.66,0.45,45,0.92],
>   'var2':['nan','2007-01-01 08:00:00','2007-01-01 09:00:00','nan','2007-01-01 10:00:00']})`
>   output:
>   `Date            sent    var1    var2
>   0   2007-01-01 07:14:00 0.32    44.00   nan
>   1   2007-01-01 07:25:00 0.34    0.66    2007-01-01 08:00:00
>   2   2007-01-01 08:00:00 0.45    0.45    2007-01-01 09:00:00
>   3   2007-01-01 09:14:00 0.70    45.00   nan
>   4   2007-01-01 09:33:12 0.22    0.92    2007-01-01 10:00:00`
>   
>   I am apply this code to calcuate sum of `sent` column on **hourly basis**
>   Input is:
>   `df=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1H')).sent.sum().reset_index()`
>   
>   Out:
>   `Date sent
>   0   2007-01-01 07:00:00 0.66
>   1   2007-01-01 08:00:00 0.45
>   2   2007-01-01 09:00:00 0.92`

- The problem is: I want to keep other columns like `var1` and `var2` with `groupby` function. I shall be grateful for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can use [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2007-01-01 07:14:00', '2007-01-01 07:25:00', '2007-01-01 08:00:00', '2007-01-01 09:14:00',
                            '2007-01-01 09:33:12']),
                   'sent': [0.32, 0.34, 0.45, 0.7, 0.22],
                   'var1': [44, 0.66, 0.45, 45, 0.92],
                   'var2': ['nan', '2007-01-01 08:00:00', '2007-01-01 09:00:00', 'nan', '2007-01-01 10:00:00']})


df['sum'] = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.hour).sent.transform('sum')

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                 Date  sent   var1                 var2   sum
0 2007-01-01 07:14:00  0.32  44.00                  nan  0.66
1 2007-01-01 07:25:00  0.34   0.66  2007-01-01 08:00:00  0.66
2 2007-01-01 08:00:00  0.45   0.45  2007-01-01 09:00:00  0.45
3 2007-01-01 09:14:00  0.70  45.00                  nan  0.92
4 2007-01-01 09:33:12  0.22   0.92  2007-01-01 10:00:00  0.92
```

Comment: Thank @ Daniel Mesejo but I also want the date in the following format so that it can show hourly basis,`0   2007-01-01 07:00:00  , 2007-01-01 08:00: 00, 2007-01-01 09:00:00 ` it is alright if it displays in new colunms.

Comment: @Faisal see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658048/python-itertools-groupby-datetime-series-by-hour